# Hidden elements still animating while display none is applied

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation, skrollr

So I'm using the [Prinzhorn skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to create a site that has text and images roll in with the scrolling or swiping of the page.  Everything works fine but I think I found a performance bug.  The way skrollr works is by using data attributes with numbers as names and the number is the point at which the animation is supposed to happen.  The values of the data attributes are css rules.

I have to use `display:none` on a few code blocks that are hidden or visible depending on screen size.  This is b/c the number in the data attribute is sometimes too large for mobile screens and the animation happens at the wrong time.

Anyways, the problem is the css in the code blocks that are hidden is calculating even while the block is set to `display:none`.

In the code below, you can see the opacity for the mobile nav block recalculating in Chrome's dev tools while at desktop widths.

```
<nav>
<!-- === Desktop and tablet === -->
<div class="hide-for-small">
  <a id="menu-btn" href="#">
    <img src="/assets/img/menu-btn.png" alt="Menu" data-600="opacity:1" data-620="opacity:0" />
    <img src="/assets/img/menu-btn-alt.png" alt="Menu" data-600="opacity:0" data-620="opacity:1 />
  </a>
</div>
<!-- === End Desktop and tablet === -->

<!-- === Mobile === -->
<div class="show-for-small">
  <a id="menu-btn" href="#">
    <img src="/assets/img/menu-btn.png" alt="Menu" data-560="opacity:1" data-580="opacity:0" />
    <img src="/assets/img/menu-btn-alt.png" alt="Menu" data-560="opacity:0" data-580="opacity:1" />
  </a>
</div>
<!-- === End Mobile === -->
```

Any thoughts on how to prevent this?  Like I said, everything looks and works fine but I'm noticing some minor lag on mobile and I'm betting it's b/c the device is having to do the same calculations twice.

Comment: What if instead of duplicating elements, you just set the data attribute, based on screen size, before the skrollr script is called? Something like `if(screen.width <= 480){document.getElementById('...').setAttribute(...);}`

Comment: @DrydenLong Just to clarify, are you talking about injecting each data attr with JS on each element that needs different data attrs?

Comment: Yes, you remove the `.show-for-small` div and define the `data-600`/`data-560` via JS that way skrollr has much less markup to traverse and only has to do the calculations once.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about doing it that way.  The only problem I see with that is it locks down the data attrs and the site wouldn't adjust if someone resized their window unless I put in window resize events.

Comment: That's just wrapping it all in a simple `window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){// do stuff here});` so it shouldn't be too much of a pain. You'll have some overhead with applying the data attributes, but that should happen before the user begins scrolling so it won't effect the skrollr performance

Comment: Yeah, that should do the trick.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem! It would probably be easiest to assign a couple of classes to all of the images, 1 for your standard image and another for your alt image then just loop over those.